# Text and images overlapping on single website

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have a problem as described above. All the other webpages are rendering correctly except one. That webpage is a Finnish newspapers' website: http://www.hs.fi

This is what the problem looks like ([link to full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nivmk.jpg)):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nivmk.jpg]

The problem only exists on this one single computer. The website works fine on all the other devices that are connected to the same router. 2 Ubuntu-laptops and Nexus 7 2013

I'm not sure if this affects anything, but the site allows you to read 5 articles and then you have to clean your cookies. I've done this multiple times and everything was working fine. The problem didn't appear on browser update or anything like that. 
The problem exists on all browsers, firefox, IE and chrome are tested. I've ran ccleaner, cleaned chache, cookies etc.

When i tried to access the website through a proxy, it seemed to be working fine. I was wondering if my external IP caused the problem but my nexus 7 2013 for example uses the same ext. IP and the site worked fine.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've never had a similar problem and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I'm using Win 7 Home Premium 64bit.

Feel free to ask additional questions if needed :)

Comment: That's just a borked CSS. Reloading the page with CTRL+SHIFT+r should already do the trick. Otherwise check if you are loading some kind of custom CSS or use a request blocker, such as RequestPolicy in Firefox.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+r seemed not to do anything. Just a little longer refresh and the problem persisted. I also tried RequestPolicy in firefox but the problem only became worse. Now the page is plain white with some links on the left side when viewing with firefox. I'm not quite sure how to confirm that I'm not loading any custom CSS, even though I think I'm not..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: I enabled something like common HTTP settings under the enable/disable Windows features menu and the problem disappeared. (Not correct translations)